# Displaying large matrices in matlab with pause when screen is filled?

Tags: matlab

Is there a function to display large array on command prompt with displaying only part of it and waiting until user enters something from keyboard.

Comment: For future reference: usage questions of (matlab), while on topic here, can often receive better/quicker attention (looking at the questions tagged ¨matlab¨, Ed Gorcenski´s quick and informative answer is unfortunately not yet the norm for such questions) if you ask somewhere like [MatLab Central](http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/). (And who knows, maybe asking this question there would prompt them to code in such a feature.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent to the *nix `more` flag, sadly.

The quickest fix is to do the following:

```
k = 8; %number of columns to display
l = 20; %number of rows to display
for i=i:k:size(A,2)
    for j = 1:l:size(A,1)
        A(j:j+l,i:i+k)
        input('');
    end
end
```

Which will page the matrix row-wise first, then column-wise (swap the loops if you want the opposite).

You may also need to put in conditionals to handle index out of bounds, etc. but I chose not to clutter the code with that.